# hibernate hard coded values annotation

Tags: hibernate, filter

I was wondering if there is a way to have a filter annotation with a hard coded values. I am joining two tables called itemRate and ratemaster. Rate master has a composite key of application rateid and ratekind id. The rate kind id can be 1 of 3 id's (primary, component, item rate).

My Item Rate table knows the application and references two different columns item_rate and rate (which is the primary rate),

My question is, is there a way with hibernate to hard code a filter so when i call `getRate()` it will filter on all rates with a rate kind id of 0 and when i call `getItemRate()` it will filter on all rates with a ratekind id of 2?

I tried doing something like this to get the rate masters with a rate kind of 0:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "CIITM_RATE", nullable = false , updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "RATE"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CIITM_APPLICATION", nullable = false , updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION") })
@FilterJoinTable(name = "kindId", condition="RATEKINDID = 0")
public Ciratemaster getRateMaster() {
    return rateMaster;
}
```

and this to get rate masters with rate kinds of 2:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "CIITM_ITEM_RATE", nullable = false , updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "RATE"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CIITM_APPLICATION", nullable = false , updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION") })
@FilterJoinTable(name = "kindId", condition="RATEKINDID = 2")
public Ciratemaster getItemRateMaster() {
   return itemRateMaster;
}
```

I tried searching hibernate website and other sites and nothing has really worked. I always come up with the error that it fetched more than 1 result when it shouldn't

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead of filters:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Where(clause = "RATEKINDID = 2")
```

Edit: Try the JoinColumnsOrFormula annotation:

```
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "2", referencedColumnName = "RATEKINDID")),
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "CIITM_RATE", nullable = false , updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "RATE")),
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "CIITM_APPLICATION", nullable = false , updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION"))
})
```

Comment: I tried that and also
`@org.hibernate.annotations.WhereJoinTable(clause = "RATEKIND = 2")`

Comment: Can you verify the SQL that is actually being produced doesn't have the clause?  Because that should work just fine.  I'd also verify with your database that there's *really* just one result using the actual query being generated.

Comment: The query that shows up is from a named query request and doesn't have the where clause associated with it. The named query looks like:

`query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Fciitem.NAMEDQUERY_FINDBYAPPLICATIONANDACCOUNT);`
`query.setParameter(Fciitem.NAMEDQUERYPARAMETER_ACCOUNT,accountNum);`
`List<Fciitem> items = query.getResultList();`

Comment: Also, apparently there is a bug where hibernate doesn't recognize WhereJoinTable on ManyToOne

Comment: You need to turn on SQL logging and get the exact query that's generated.  Saying the query doesn't show up because it's from a named query doesn't make any sense.  Additionally, Object.VERYLONGSTATICVALUES don't mean anything without some definition behind them.

Comment: Sorry,

It wont let me copy and past the complete output of hibernate but its like this:

`select
        fciitem0_.CIITM_APPLICATION as CIITM1_983_,
        .. 
    from
        CIS.FCIITEM fciitem0_ 
    where
        fciitem0_.CIITM_COMP=1 
        and fciitem0_.CIITM_APPLICATION=? 
        and fciitem0_.CIITM_CUST=? 
        and fciitem0_.CIITM_SERVICE=0`

Comment: and the static name query is defined as

`select fciitem from Fciitem fciitem where fciitem.id.ciitmComp = 1 and fciitem.id.ciitmApplication = :application and fciitem.id.ciitmCust = :accountNumber and fciitem.ciitmService = 0`

Comment: Is there a way to add virtual columns that i can reference in my join columns? These virtual columns can have the hard coded values that I need to reference.

Comment: Try using @JoinColumnsOrFormulas instead.  I'll update my answer to show the usage.

Comment: I saw that and was going to try it but the version of hibernate i'm using doesn't have that. Its an older version. Thanks though